# For loop with two indexes?

Tags: python

What does a for loop with two indexes do?

For example

```
for a, b in c:
```

What does this statement do?

Comment: It depends on the data structure you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If c is an iterable object which has elements that can be unpacked, then you can use two variables to loop through c. For example, consider the example below -

```
c = [(1,2),(3,4)];

for a,b in c: 
    print(a,b)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
1 2
3 4
```

Here, we have used two variables which are nothing but the unpacked elements from elements of `c`. You can use it in such cases, where you are wishing to simultaneously access inner elements of an element as in the example.

---

**NOTE:**

You need to be sure that all elements in your iterable are consistent in their dimensions. For example, the above example wouldn't work if there are elements in `c` like -

```
c = [[1,1],[1,2],[3]];
```

The above line would result in an error saying -

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

---

In the same way, the above approach can be extended to use more than two like -

```
c = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,[1,2,3]]];

for a,b,d in c: 
    print(a,b,d)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 [1, 2, 3]
```

---

### USE CASES -

1. One common use case of this is in a dictionary. You can access both keys and values of a dictionary while iterating over it using this way of looping as -

   ```
   c = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3};

   for key,value in c.items(): 
       print(key,value)
   ```

   **OUTPUT :**

   ```
   a 1
   b 2
   c 3
   ```

---

2. This is also used when we are using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in python to iterate through multiple variables at once but need to access the values simultaneously as -

   ```
   l1 = [1,2,3];
   l2 = [4,5,6];

   for list1,list2 in zip(l1,l2): 
       print(list1, list2)
   ```

   **OUTPUT :**

   ```
   1 4
   2 5
   3 6
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this style to iterate over dictionary or list of tuples, or list of list as well
Example:

```
my_list = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
for a, b in my_list:
    print (a, b)
```

The above loop will give output as:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant to use `{`? I remember sets not retaining order, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tuples

```
[(0,1), (0, 2), (5,3)]
```

You can loop over this:

```
for i, j in my_list:
    print("i", i, "j", j)
```

Resulting in

```
i 0 j 1
i 0 j 2
i 5 j 3
```

Answer (score 0):

c could be a tuple and a, b is unpacking the tuple into 2 variables.

```
c = [(5, 7), (5, 8)]
for a, b in c:
   print(a , b)

5 7
5 8
```

Comment: Why say c could be a tuple and then not make it a tuple?